# Saving coredata on background thread causes fetching into a deadlock and crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm saving coredata in a background method (parent-child) but fetching is done on main thread. So i'm getting a deadlock in the fetch method and sometimes app crashed. Is there anything wrong i'm doing? How can i improve both save and fetch without affect main thread? I have read many documents but none of them explaining me how to use both in a project. If this is a wrong question please guide me to proper solution and let me know my mistakes please.

```
-(ThreadInfo *)retrieveSolicitationInfoForThreadID:(NSString*)inThreadID;
{
NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail ==   %@",loginUser];
 NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"threadID == %@",inThreadID];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[userPredicate, threadPredicate]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
if(fetchedObjects.count!=0)
{
    ThreadInfo *threadInfo=[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    return threadInfo;
}
 return nil;
}
```

**SAVE**

```
-(void)updateThreadEntityWithSyncDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)inDictionary
  {

 NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

 AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

  //    NSManagedObjectContext *writerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
  //   [writerContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[sharedDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

 // create main thread MOC
   context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]        initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
     context.parentContext = writerContext;

    NSManagedObjectContext *contextforThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

   contextforThread.parentContext = context;

  [contextforThread performBlock:^{




NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:contextforThread];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",loginUser];
NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"threadID == %@",[inDictionary valueForKey:@"thread"]];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[userPredicate, threadPredicate]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [contextforThread executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
for (ThreadInfo *threadInfo in fetchedObjects)
{
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"userEmail"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.userEmail=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"userEmail"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"badgeValue"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.badgeValue=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"badgeValue"];
        }
    }


    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice4Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice4Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice4Percentage"];
        }
    }
    if([[inDictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"choice5Percentage"])
    {
        if([inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"]!=[NSNull null])
        {
            threadInfo.choice5Percentage=[inDictionary valueForKey:@"choice5Percentage"];
        }
    }

 }

    NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Child error : %@",error);

    }

    [context performBlock:^{
        NSError *error;
        if(![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
               }];
    }];


 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your fetch.  You are fetching two strings against what I am guessing is a large number of entities in your store.  Your fetch performance is 100% of your issue.

A) You should not be doing string compares if it can be avoided
B) You should not be doing TWO string compares ever

Your data model needs to be refactored.  Doing two string compares against a table that has a large number of entities is going to perform badly no matter what.

### Update

Your data structure is bad.  I don't know how many ways I can say that.  Ideally you want an integer or other number structure as your unique identifier.

Since you are not telling me/us how many entities you are dealing with I can only guess you have a large number.  How man results are expected?  One? Or Many?  Is this a unique constraint that you are working against?  If not, why isn't there a unique constraint coming from your server?  If it is a unique constraint why haven't you limited the fetch size like I suggested?

You are not giving me any information but hoping I can magically fix your problem.

Reducing it to one string is something you can try but you are asking **me** how **your** data is going to behave.  TEST it.  You have instruments and you have the data.  Change things and compare the results.

Strings are expensive.  They always have been and always will be.

### Update

Since it is a unique constraint you can do yourself a large favor and change your code just a bit:

```
- (ThreadInfo *)retrieveSolicitationInfoForThreadID:(NSString*)inThreadID;
{
    NSString *loginUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

    AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ThreadInfo"];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    //Since there is every only one tell SQL to stop looking after one
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:1]; 

    /* Change these to your single constraint
    NSPredicate *userPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail ==   %@",loginUser];
    NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"threadID == %@",inThreadID];
    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[userPredicate, threadPredicate]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];
    */

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return [fetchedObjects lastObject];
}
```

Setting the fetch limit will cause the store to stop looking after the first match which will reduce the fetch time.  Moving it to a single string also reduces the fetch time.

In the future, avoid strings in this situation.  Doing an integer primary key is incredibly fast and will avoid this performance problem entirely.

Comment: Sir, that is the issue,but I'm confused how could i improve fetch since i need to compare two strings. can you please suggest me some method or logic?

Comment: the method is simple really, DO NOT do two string compares against a large number of entities.  That is painfully expensive.  Redesign the data.

Comment: You can probably put a bandaid on it by chanting the fetch limit to 1 (assuming you are looking for a unique) and see if that improves it.  You can also index those two properties in the entity but both of those are stop gaps.  You have a bad design in your data later.

Comment: Sir if i use async fetch, will it help?

Comment: ASync fetch will **NOT** help because the fetch is the issue.  It will always block the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` which is your core issue.  Limiting the batch size **might** help but no guarantee.  You need to test.  What you really need to do is fix your data structure.  Searching for two strings is non-performant.  Always has been, always will be.

Comment: Batch updates were introduced in iOS 8 not iOS 7.  Considering the issues you are having, I would **not** recommend using that API as it has a number of risks associated with it.

Comment: i can reduce two string into one, is that ok? i can reduce data structure but most of the cases i need to use fetch, I'm really stuck this point, How can i make fetch without affecting UI? For saving coredata I'm using the method you suggested http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/02/the-concurrent-core-data-stack/ and now its better and profiler showing no time for save data. but freezing i still there because of fetch.

Comment: The size doesn't matter and I do not recommend following the advice of that post.  He has not provided any data to support his (incorrect) assumptions.  Your fetch is the issue.  Reducing to one string will probably help but finding a way to do it without strings would be MUCH better.  Reducing the number of objects returned (1fetchLimit:1`) will help also.  Is this a unique constraint?  I have asked that before and the answer matters.

Comment: Sir i have changed my saving into http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/ your method.

Answer (score -1):

facing to problems such as coreData and multiplyThreads,you should add the following code in the corresponding method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: cdm.managedObjectContext selector: @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object: nil];
```

Then the coreData changes at a thread,it will instantly update it in another thread where the coreData is being used.

Wish the answer will help you!

Comment: you mean in fetching method?

Comment: i mean your crash maybe two threads operate the coreData which leads to crash.